# jQuery Tools tabs - content not showing

Tags: jquery, tabs

After looking around at a way to build nice tabs and finding MANY that just don't work, I came across jQuery Tools. It works nicely. Here's the HTML http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html and the CSS http://jquerytools.org/media/css/tabs-no-images.css.

The problem is that when I add content to the div elements, ie. the panes where tab content goes, it just won't show up. I have a page that contains a form and a table yet if I insert that code it does nothing to the tabs, they just appear as they are without any content.

Am I missing something?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Wait a second, I've just found the answer! For some reason, the demo CSS had for the div's "display: none".